# Moxtra Oauth when using optional parameters returns "Unexpected character ('<' (code 60))

Tags: post, oauth, optional-parameters

I've just started to test out the optional calls for Oauth

as soon as I add an optional parameter, I get this error

> {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Unexpected character
>   ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array,
>   object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source:
>   java.io.StringReader@2c6cc0b9; line: 1, column: 2]"}

Without the optionals I get the expected response.

Is there a fix??

Here are 2 POST examples

Doesn't work

> client_id=foo&client_secret=bar&grant_type=GRANT_TYPE&uniqueid=3&timestamp=1429249458176&signature=SIGNATURE&firstname=John

Works

> client_id=foo&client_secret=bar&grant_type=GRANT_TYPE&uniqueid=3&timestamp=1429249458176&signature=SIGNATURE

I would like to add lastname, pictureurl and timezone.
I tried with all four (firstname, lastname, pictureurl, timezone) combinations; returns the same error as above.